# Permission denied when running nagios plugin

Tags: nagios

I just wrote a simple bash script that check if filesystem is working writing and deleting a file, but when I put it into Nagios, it never runs as expected.

```
root@debian:~# cat /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_filesys.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Script que checa se file system consegue escrever/ler arquivos
if  touch teste.txt && rm teste.txt; then
    echo OK - Teste OK!
    exit 0
else
    echo CRITICAL - Teste de escrita/leitura falhou!
    exit 2
fi


root@debian:~# ls -l /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_filesys.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 217 Feb  5 10:40 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_filesys.sh
```

I also found a debug script to see what is the problem, and that's the output:

```
 2016-1-5 13:31:16 ------ debugging
 cmd=[/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_filesys.sh]
 output=[touch: cannot touch `teste.txt': Permission denied
 CRITICAL - Teste de escrita/leitura falhou!
```

I tried inserting the nagios user in the /etc/sudoers file as :

```
nagios ALL:NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_filesys.sh *
```

but the problem persists. OBS: I'm checking in localhost.

Comment: Did you actually [define the command](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#command) in your config?

Comment: @Victor Ide, what do you mean by: "it never run as expected"? What error does nagios show?

Comment: I did in the localhost.cfg, and when I open the web page I can see the Service in CRITICAL status.

Comment: @bangal well my file system is mounted, so expected means that the output should be OK - Teste OK!

Comment: @VictorIde; according to your debug, the error seems to be permission related and I am sure the nagios user has not enough permission to create file in the directory. So chek on that.

Comment: @bangal Yea I tried changing even the directory permission, as 
`root@debian:~# ls -l /usr/lib/nagios
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  1 15:36 cronjobs
drwsrwsrwx 2 root root 4096 Feb  5 10:40 plugins
´

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a full path for the touch/rm, because your script is trying to run in `/`, and Nagios doesn't have write permission to `/`.

(You might be able to get away with using `~/test.txt` if $HOME is set to something sane.)

You can verify this for yourself:

```
# pgrep nagios
556
# ls -ls /proc/556/cwd
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  5 11:10 /proc/556/cwd -> /
```

This indicates that the Nagios process is running with `cwd` set to `/`

Answer (score 0):

Your nagios plugin will run as your "nrpe_user" that you have defined in your /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg.  This is probably 'user nagios or user nrpe.'

If you update your script to touch '/tmp/teste.txt' (in other words, touch a file in a location with open permissions) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `nagios` in the `sudoers` file won't help **if you don't actually invoke sudo**.  Try

```
nagios ALL=ALL NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_filesys.sh
```

in `sudoers`, and have nagios invoke

```
sudo /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_filesys.sh
```